# How to match UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace to my color values

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor, cgcolor, cgcolorspace

I set the color for `UIButton` with the XCode visual editor. I set it using RGB sliders.[image]

Then I set variable `green`:

```
let green = UIColor(red: 0, green: 210/255, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
```

When I printed out `green` value and `UIButton.backgroundColor` I got next values accordingly:

```
UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace -0.146119 0.836984 -0.0130851 1
UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0.823529 0 1
```

So, as I guess, the color spaces are equal, but values are not. Why is it so? The Apple's UIButton() does some hidden conversion? What is the purpose? Is it possible to have the same values for this button property and for `green` property.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Next to the "RGB Sliders" popup menu there is a button which 
allows you to choose a color space:

[image]

In your case it is set to "Display P3", a color space which is
"larger" than the sRGB color space and allows to display more
colors on newer devices with a P3 display. This color is represented
in the "extended sRGB colorspace" where the components are not 
restricted to the range from 0.0 to 1.0 (see "Color and Color Spaces" in [UIColor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor)
for more information). In your case

```
UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace -0.416964 0.838774 -0.249501 1
```

with negative red and blue components, i.e. a color outside color gamut
of sRGB.

If you set the colorspace in the color chooser to "sRGB" then the result for 0/210/0 will be

```
UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0.823529 0 1
```

and identical to

```
let green = UIColor(red: 0, green: 210/255, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
```

Alternatively, use the Display P3 color space for the programmatically
created color as well:

```
print(label.backgroundColor!)
// UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace -0.416964 0.838774 -0.249501 1

let green = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0, green: 210/255, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
print(green)
// UIDisplayP3ColorSpace 0 0.823529 0 1
print(UIColor(cgColor: green.cgColor))
// UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace -0.416964 0.838774 -0.249501 1

print(label.backgroundColor! == green)
// true
```

Comment: Thank you for a nice comprehensive answer!

Comment: How can I convert such a color to a UIColor in code?