# Wrong UIColor in CAGradientLayer

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, colors, uicolor

I'm having some problems to apply a CAGradientLayer to my view.

One of the color that I need is that:
[image: Right Color]

So I wrote this code for the gradient:

```
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = self.button.bounds
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.init(red: 238/255, green: 34/255, blue: 84/255, alpha: 1).cgColor,
                        UIColor.init(red: 237/255, green: 144/255, blue: 78/255, alpha: 1).cgColor]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.2, y: 0.5)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.8, y: 0.5)
    gradient.cornerRadius = button.layer.cornerRadius
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient2, at: 1)
```

But the result is that (not only on the simulator but also on my iPhone):

[image: Wrong Color]

this happens every time I use a color in my app, not only on a CAGradientLayer. Why?

Comment: Very likely different color profiles... Take a read through this article (not mine) and see if it makes sense / solves your issue: http://inaka.net/blog/2014/09/05/getting-the-right-colors-in-your-ios-app/

Comment: I see that you're using Sketch and assume you're also using Zeplin. If you click on the button in Zeplin, it will show you the gradient colors chosen by your designer, rather than having to use Digital Color Meter.

Comment: I think your problem is in the RGB conversion. As far as I remember `238/255` will be converted to int (it will be 0) so you need to divide a float value to get a float value which will result in a correct color.

Comment: Thank you DonMag, you solved my problem!

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47443647/how-to-match-uiextendedsrgbcolorspace-to-my-color-values